# TypeError: mul() argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not ReLU

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to add a `torch.nn.ReLU()` layer between fc1 and fc2 layer.

Original code:

model:

```py
# ...
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4096, 256)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 4096)
# ...
```

```
def forward(...):
    # ...
    x = x.view(-1, 4096)
    x = self.fc1(x))
    if a7 is not None:
        x = x * a7.squeeze()
    # ...
```

I tried

```py
# ...
x = x.view(-1, 4096)
x = nn.ReLU(self.fc1(x)))
if a7 is not None:
    x = x * a7.squeeze()
# ...
```

and this error pops out.

Comment: Did you really mean `__init__:` or was it supposed to be `def forward(...):`?

Comment: Right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: No problem. I fixed it in your question, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes `__init__` was a typo and it should be `forward`. Let me know if that is not the case and I'll delete it.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, with_relu=False):
    super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3, 10), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)) if with_relu else nn.Linear(3, 10)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 3)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.fc1(x)
    print(torch.min(x))  # just to show you ReLU is working...
    return self.fc2(x)

# Model without ReLU
net_without_relu = SimpleModel(with_relu=False)
print(net_without_relu)

# Model with ReLU
net_with_relu = SimpleModel(with_relu=True)
print(net_with_relu)

# random input data
x = torch.randn((5, 3))
print(x)

# we expect it to print something < 0
output1 = net_without_relu(x)

# we expect it to print 0.
output2 = net_with_relu(x)
```

You can check the code below running on the Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W3Dh4_KPd3iABx5FSzZm3tilm6tnJh0v

---

To use as you tried:

```py
x = nn.ReLU(self.fc1(x)))
```

you can use the functional API:

```py
from torch.nn import functional as F

# ...
x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying out this now

Answer (score 0):

You should not do any view methods in `__init__`.
Init should hold your structure.
For instance this is copied from AlexNet `__init__`

```
nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
```

Your forward method however, may contain reshaping, calculations, functions.

---

`nn.Sequential` should be part of the `__init__` like in AlexNet:

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 256 * 6 * 6)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

And then you can use class attributes `self.features`, `self.classifier` in forward.

**<sub>Note: this is an old model of AlexNet from PyTorch 0.4 but it is fairly simple and the logic is the same</sub>**

Comment: Thanks. So what is the most convenient way to add Relu() here? I tried `self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4096, 256), nn.ReLU()) ` but still doen't work.

Comment: Check out the [example](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/_modules/torchvision/models/alexnet.html),  what you just wrote cannot work.